# Yii Authorized action

Tags: yii

```
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->addCondition(array('where' => 'book_id = ' . $id));
    $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Copy', array(
        'criteria' => $criteria
    ));
    $this->render('specificCopy', array(
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ));
    //------//
    array('allow', 
            'actions' => array('specificCopy'),
            'users' => array('*'),
        ),
```

like this ?
or something wrong ?

by these code, i want to retrieve data from 'Copy' mdoel with some criteria as shown.
but, when i render it to view (specificCopy), my apps show this error :

Error 403
You are not authorized to perform this action.

can anybody help me ?

Comment: what is the function(action) name and did you add your action name in rules?

Comment: public function actionSpecificCopy($id){
//these code;
}

i dont get your point about the rules.
what rules ?

Comment: add 'specificCopy' in your rules in your controller

Comment: did you add `specificCopy` in rules?

Comment: maybe i have to edit my code above to show you

Answer (score 2):

in your **controller**
Add **'specificCopy'** in **rules**

```
public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',  
                'actions'=>array('index','view','specificCopy'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
            array('allow', 
                'actions'=>array('create','update','captcha','specificCopy'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
            array('allow',
                'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
                'users'=>array('admin'),
            ),
            array('deny',  // deny all users
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }
```